# React Native Expo: No App Configuration Data

Tags: node.js, react-native, ios-simulator, expo

I just tried to open my project on expo after making some changes to my backend code, now I am getting a No App Configuration Data message and I am unable to do anything. I am not seeing any errors in my console, only warnings. The change I made to my backend shouldn't impact my app's configuration. I just added values to a model and updated a controller for those values. I "Reset Content and Settings" on my simulator and did another npm install to update my packages and still having this issue.    [image: No App Configuration Data]

Comment: Did you get it working? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: getting the same issue. Did you find any solution?